# getting lines to move over in JS

Tags: javascript

Super basic JS question. Im trying to get 4 red and blue stripes.

```
function start() {
    var row = 0;
    var blue = 0;
    var red = 100;

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var rect = new Rectangle (100, 100);
            rect.setPosition(blue , row);
            rect.setColor(Color.blue);
            add(rect);

            var rect2 = new Rectangle (100, 100);
            rect2.setPosition(red , row);
            rect2.setColor(Color.red);
            add(rect2);

            row += 100;
        }
        blue += 200;
        red += 200;
    }

}
```

with this code its printing 2 of the lines but not all 4. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

When you create more than one element with the same name you have to use [] so

```
    add(rect2[0]);
```

or

```
    add(rect2[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop variable. Your outer loop is not working

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    //CODE
    }
}
```